# Sublime Text 3 - Python Build System Confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, build, python-3.3, sublimetext3

First, thanks in advance for any assistance.

I'm diving into Python and would like to continue to use Sublime Text 3 as I do for other projects. As I understand it, the internal version of Python is 3.3, but I'd like to use 2.7.6. Following other examples, I created a new build system as follows:

```
{
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": '^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\', line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

When I switch to this new build, open the Console and then try to run the following command in the Python 2 syntax

```
print "Hello, world."
```

I get an "invalid syntax" error. However, if I try to run the same command in parentheses as required for Python 3

```
print("Hello, world.")
```

the command executes successfully. In other words, it does not appear that the Console is using the 2.7.6 build system.

What I find confusing is that if I save a new test.py file using the same Python 2 syntax as above, build it using the default Python 3 build system the Console outputs a successful execution of the print command – even though the syntax should not be compatible (as occurs in the Console). It seems I get different results running commands directly in the Console and running a build of file.

I'm sure this can be chalked up to a misunderstanding on my part, but I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Cheers.

Comment: The console is _independant_ of the build system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one thing you may not be aware of is that

```
print("Hello World")
```

is valid in both Python 3 and later revisions of Python 2, including 2.7.6, so if you're running your file from the command line, it'll execute properly regardless of which interpreter you're using.

You may also be confusing yourself regarding the Console in Sublime and the build systems. The Console, opened by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> or selecting `View -> Show Console`, is running Sublime's **internal** version of Python, a stripped-down Python 3.3.3 if you're using the latest build. You cannot run Py2 commands in the console, no matter how hard you try. It is useful for running Python API commands to control Sublime itself, but it's of no use in building non-[plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html) files.

[**Build Systems**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) let you run your programs through *external* compilers, interpreters, processors, or what have you. They are activated by choosing one in the `Tools -> Build System` menu, and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> on OS X) to run it.

So, to verify that your build systems are working as desired, create a new `.py` file with

```
print "Hello World"
```

in it. Save the file, and select `Tools -> Build System -> Python` (the first one in the menu, between `Make` and `Ruby`). Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> as appropriate for your OS, and check out the pane that opens at the bottom of Sublime. It should show "Hello World" at the top line, then another line saying `[Finished in 0.05 seconds]` or something similar underneath it.

Now, select `Tools -> Build System -> Python 3` (or whatever you named your new build system) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, and you should now see a traceback in the build pane for invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I was starting to get the idea that the Console was not tied to the selected build system. However, I'm still running into the unexpected execution of the Python 2 syntax when I choose the default Python build system (assumed to be 3.3) and run the build command (Command+B). I wonder if, perhaps, the default Python build system is tied to the currently installed version of Python (python --version in the terminal) and the Console is Python 3, regardless. At any rate, this does help clear things up a bit.